# XAML from file as element

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hi i want to load my element during program start from external file. 
Below is my code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FromFile3d" x:Class="FromFile3d.MainWindow"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.789,0.541" StartPoint="0.225,0.543">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.849"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF232323" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="527*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="265*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="161,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Viewport3D x:Name="_viewport3D"  />
</Grid>
```

and for last cs with load method

```
private void LoadCore()
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.xaml");
        if (path != null)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader mysr = new StreamReader(path);
                _viewport3D= XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as Viewport3D;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    String.Format("Unable to parse file:\r\n\r\n{0}",
                    e.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

and file that i want to load is Viewport3d definition with my scene and model and ends with /Viewport3D ( i couldn't paste it, don't know why )

What i'm doing wrong ? because nothing happens when program starts my model is invisible :> (it's not the problem with viewport code because it work's fine before moving to external file).

Comment: I don't recall that you can *replace* existing controls like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
_viewport3D = XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as Viewport3D;
```

You can't manipulate the control tree like that. You should instead be appending elements.

First, remove the `Viewport3D` from your XAML.

Second, give your grid a name, say `_grid`.

Third, change the aforementioned line to:

```
_grid.Children.Add(XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as Viewport3D);
```

This is the appropriate way to manipulate the control tree.

Comment: Thank you, it took me 6h and i get nowhere :). Last question in my external xaml i have storybard that i want to begin from main window but using Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("MoveSB"); like normally can't find my element. It's probably nothing but i couldn't find similar problem .

Comment: You would probably be best asking a new question.